# In-Memory Table on SQL 2014 HA cluster not queriable on Secondary nodes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, alwayson, in-memory-tables

I've set up a simple in-memory table on a high-availability group database on SQL 2014.
Querying the table from the primary node directly or from the Listener works fine.
If I change the query string to ReadOnly Intent or try to query directly from either of the 2 secondary nodes I get the following error: -

`Msg 41341, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table 'tbl_GetMakes' is not yet available on the secondary replica.`

There is very little information on this message online.  It talks about it being replicated properly when the "REDO" process takes place.  As far as I read it, the "REDO" process should be automatic, the table has been in place now for just over 24 hours and still isn't working.
Any ideas anyone?
Thanks,
Jon

Comment: strange,was the table present during initial synchronization

Comment: are you able to see the table in sys.tables on secondary

Comment: Yes, can see it in sys.tables.  I've taken out an existing regular table and replaced it with the In-Memory table.  The database was already in the HA group when I did this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sean Gallardy who answered this over on the Microsoft Forum

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a6cbeb89-bc99-491c-8c2f-9937d5ddfa6a/inmemory-table-on-sql-2014-ha-cluster-not-queriable-on-secondary-nodes?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

I've reproduced the answer from the above link below: -

That's not correct, they can absolutely be read from a readable secondary, assuming:
The in memory table was made with Durability = schema_and_data
A checkpoint has run on the primary
The proper isolation level is used
I can easily get this to work, here is a repro:
  1. Create Database on primary and put in AG

```
CREATE DATABASE [Test1]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY
( NAME = N'Test1', 
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test1.mdf' , 
  SIZE = 4096KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ), 
  FILEGROUP [IMOLTP] CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA  DEFAULT
  ( NAME = N'imoltp_dir', 
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\imoltp_dir' , 
  MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Test1_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test1_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1280KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

2. Create the IM Table and populate

> CREATE TABLE dbo.IMOLTP
>      (
>      C1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 1000)
>      ) 
>      WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA)
>
> INSERT INTO dbo.IMOLTP(C1) VALUES (1), (2), (3)
>      GO
>
> CHECKPOINT
>
> SELECT * FROM dbo.IMOLTP

3. Read from a READABLE secondary

> Use Test1
>      GO
>
> SELECT * FROM dbo.IMOLTP
>      GO

It works just fine for me on: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU3) (KB3204388) - 12.0.5538.0 (X64)

-Sean

Comment: Your edit makes this answer *less* useful since it's now effectively a link-only answer. Answers can link to resources but they should be *useful* in their own right, whether or not the site(s) that they're linking to is currently available or not.